# How to Select the records of one table and use them as the fields to create another Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have gone through all the various suggestions but none seems to matches the requirement. This is NOT a Pivot Table. The first table (Course_table) has a list of course, about 1,200. I want to create a second table (marksheet_table) which has as its columns the rows of the first table. How can you create the marksheet_table in PHP and SQL (MySQL) using the records in the first Table as its field names eg.

```
Course_table    
 |  Subject |   unit    |   staff   |
--------------------------------------------------
 |  Math    |   3       |   Mr James    |   
 |  Econs   |   1       |   Dr Smith    |   
 |  Chem    |   2       |   Mrs Aisha   |       



Marksheet_table    
studentid | Math    |   Econs   |   Chem    |
--------------------------------------------------
10001     | 10      |     20    |     30    |
10045     | 11      |     09    |     45    |


 <?php
  include 'config.php'; 
  mysql_select_db("DB_Subject", $conn);
  $Select_sql = mysql_query(" SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM Course_table");   
        while($row= mysql_fetch_array($Select_sql)) 
        { $CourseCode   = $row["CourseCode"] ;
            $Create_sql = mysql_query(" CREATE TABLE Marksheet_table (  
                                    studentId INT(8) NOT NULL,
                                    $subject DECIMAL(4,2), --Math101
                                    $subject DECIMAL(4,2), --ECO302
                                    $subject DECIMAL(4,2), --CHEM112
                                        ");     
                }
          mysql_fetch_array($Create_sql) ;
        mysql_close($conn); 

   ?>
```

Comment: Surely you can do that more efficiently than creating a table with 1200 columns?!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jeroen's comment on the question. However, to answer the question:

You just need to build up your sql query:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
mysql_select_db("DB_Subject", $conn);
$Select_sql = mysql_query(" SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM Course_table");
$statement = "CREATE TABLE Marksheet_table ( studentId INT(8) NOT NULL, ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Select_sql)) {
    $CourseCode = $row["CourseCode"];
    $statement .= $row["subject"] . " DECIMAL(4,2), " ;
}
$statement = rtrim($statement, ',') ;
$statement .= ")" ; 
$Create_sql = mysql_query($statement);
mysql_fetch_array($Create_sql);
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```